# Create Username Table on registration

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello all I am working to get this project to work, in a in house website and looking to get users there own tables for various reasons if you could please help on why this is not working that would be great.

```
$sql="insert into users(username,password) values('".$_REQUEST['username']."', '".$_REQUEST['password']."')";

$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE '".$_REQUEST['username']."'
         (
         ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
         PRIMARY KEY(ID),
         workorder CHAR(15),
         waybill  CHAR(15),
         shipper CHAR(15),
         partname CHAR(15),
         rnumber CHAR(15)
         )";

$res=mysql_query($sql,$sql2);
```

Comment: This looks like a SQL injection waiting to happen...

Comment: You forgot to show us, what is the error message, when you try to run your code!

Comment: Why do you want, or need, one table per user to store orders?

Comment: I am building a website for organizing data for a person that signup in the company I work for, for example if you register you get a table with the data the site is set up for and to access that data so once you click on the page to load data it will look in your table, so you may edit, delete, or add data without affecting other users data. and if one users table becomes corrupted it dose not affect all the other people on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all:** The MYSQL extension in PHP is deprecated! Check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Here is another one to help you to choose a proper extension: http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

**There is an error in your code:**

```
$res=mysql_query($sql,$sql2);
```

The second argument of the mysql_query() function is a string (in your code), but the function requires a mysql connection (resource) there.

You have to run your queries with separate mysql_query() calls:

```
$res1=mysql_query($sql, $mysqlLink);
$res2=mysql_query($sql2, $mysqlLink);
```

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/mysql_query):

```
mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

**Note 1**: avoid to build your queries with string concatenations without any escaping! Your code is vulnerable against [SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)! Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (or at least [escaping](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)) to address this issue!

**Note 2**: never ever store passwords in plain text!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a personal debugging service. Please don't feed the help vampires

Comment: I appoligize if im not understanding this properly but I am one that dose not copy and paste code, I would like to learn about all code that I enter into my website, this is also a beta website will be securing encrypting passwords once beta is finished. Is there a manual to explain all this or a link anyone knows about this to explain in detail about the problem I am having?

Comment: @Bojangles: This is why, I added additional information.

Comment: @user3698349 Just search for the keywords: `php hash password`

Comment: $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE '".$_REQUEST['username']."'
     (
     ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     PRIMARY KEY(ID),
     workorder CHAR(15),
     waybill CHAR(15),
     shipper CHAR(15),
     partname CHAR(15),
     rnumber CHAR(15)
     )";
Can you see any problems with that sql, in my mind it should be working but I don't understand what I am missing I am sorry if this is causing a problem. it dose not show me any errors....